# In specific page, run function to edit title

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins

I want to execute a function in a specific page only, that edits the post title of posts inside a post-grid plugin.

I tried:

```
if (is_page('my-slug')) { add_filter(...); } //page slug

if (is_page('12345')) { add_filter(...); } //page ID

add_filter('the_title', 'title_with_attributes', 10, 2);
function title_with_attributes($title, $id) {
    if (is_page('12345') || is_page('my-slug')) { 
        //Do stuff ...
    }
}
```

With no results. The function is the following and runs fine.

```
function title_with_attributes($title, $id) {
    global $wp_query;
    if(get_post_type($post->ID)=="product"){
        global $post;
        //get other variables from post here ...
        $title = "add text and vars ".$title;
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Maybe there is a way to add this function when the plugin runs but I do not know how. The plugin is the "Post-Grid" from WP Bakery

Comment: _“I tried: […]”_ - where exactly? functions.php of the theme? The system probably doesn’t know what page you are on at that point already. You need to do this the other way around: Add the filter, without any conditions - and then _inside_ the callback function, check what page your on, and dependent on that do something, or not.

Comment: I was thinking the same way. So I did what you said. Add filter > function title_with_attributes > inside the function check if is_page.